# Cannot cast from JsonElement to String while parsing from the JSON file

Tags: java, json

This is my first code for reading from a Json file but I keep getting an error message:
 Can not cast from JasonElement to String

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Json 
{  
    public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

try 
{

    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\dell\\eclipse-
workspace\\Assignment\\data.json"));

    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) obj;

String name = (String) jsonObject.get("Name");
String author = (String) jsonObject.get("Author");
System.out.println("Name: " + name);
System.out.println("Author: " + author);
}
   catch (Exception e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
    }

}
```

Excuse me for any silly mistakes.
I am still a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want.

If `Name` needs to be an actual JSON string value (as in, it must be `{ "Name": "str" }` and *not* `{ "Name": [] }`), then you should say `jsonObject.get("Name").getAsString()`. This causes an error if it isn't a string, which is desirable.

Otherwise, use `jsonObject.get("Name").toString()`, which returns a valid JSON value, as a `String`. E.g.

```
{ "Name": "a" } -> "a" (That's a string, 3 characters, two quote marks and an 'a')
{ "Name": false } -> false (That's a string, 5 chars, no quotes)
```

Answer (score 4):

By involking jsonObject.get("Name")  you will get a JsonElement object and you can not cast to String. Maybe you can try:

```
jsonObject.get("Name").toString();
```